# AdMob eCPM Floor Beta publisher id

Tags: admob

after I created new AdMob eCPM Floor and I selected which App/Site I already have , I get new publisher ID called "Mediation ID".. should I change the site ID on my already app on play store to this new one ? or eCPM floor will work probably?

cause I have now 2 publisher IDs , App ID and eCPM ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have one mediationID which is the ID from the Admob mediation screen.
You probably have 2 Admob publisherIds, one for the eCPM floor and one for non-floor.

Your app should use the mediationId.
Your mediation config (on the Admob mediation page) should refer to the 2 other publisherIds.